# How to show Windows forms continuously in extended monitor even if primary is locked

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, dashboard, multiple-monitors

In our project we have a requirement to display dashboards (Windows forms) in the extended displays connected to the CPU.

Currently we are able to display the dashboards in the extended display, but the extended display does not show anything once system (primary) got locked.

We are not allowed to do any changes with respect to workstation locking.

We have to show the Dashboards on extended displays even if primary is locked. And is there any to remove the dependency on primary, once dashboards are sent to extended displays?

We are using VS2013 and C#.

Thanks,
Srikk

Comment: "We are not allowed to do any changes with respect to Work station locking." Pretty sure this is a windows thing and there's no way around it without "making changes to work station locking." To expand on this, windows locks all displays when you lock the computer - for obvious reasons. It wouldn't make sense to lock the computer and still display the desktop/files. Unless you don't actually "lock" the computer, the secondary display will be locked by windows (assuming this is the operating system you're using).

Answer (score 3):

"We are not allowed to do any changes with respect to Work station locking."

Pretty sure this is a windows thing and there's no way around it without "making changes to work station locking." To expand on this, windows locks all displays when you lock the computer - for obvious reasons. It wouldn't make sense to lock the computer and still display the desktop/files. Unless you don't actually "lock" the computer, the secondary display will be locked by windows (assuming this is the operating system you're using).

To expand on this, it's possible to not actually lock the computer, but create a global key/mouse hook (don't forget that you also need to go to extra lengths to lock <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DELETE</kbd> if you want to do it right) to ignore all key presses/mouse movements.

I don't have the code written in C# on me, but here is the AutoIt code I wrote that locks my keyboard and mouse and displays flying nyan cats all over my screen. If someone presses a key, it locks the computer (the real way) through windows API.

```
;///////////////////////////////
;// Lock Code Created by DT   //
;///////////////////////////////
#include <WinApi.au3>
#include <GUIConstantsEx.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>

Sleep(5000);

;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
;// Hook User32.dll to block Mouse/Keyboard Input and Monitor //
;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Global $stub_KeyProc = DllCallbackRegister("_KeyProc", "int", "int;ptr;ptr")
Global $stub_MouseProc = DllCallBackRegister("_MouseProc", "int", "int;ptr;ptr")
Global $keyboardHook = _WinAPI_SetWindowsHookEx($WH_KEYBOARD_LL, DllCallbackGetPtr($stub_KeyProc), _WinAPI_GetModuleHandle(0), 0)
Global $mouseHook = _WinAPI_SetWindowsHookEx($WH_MOUSE_LL, DllCallbackGetPtr($stub_MouseProc), _WinAPI_GetModuleHandle(0), 0)

;//////////////////////
;// Global Variables //
;//////////////////////
Global $lock = False                                    ;If a key is pressed, set this to True and handle it in our while loop (gets messy otherwise)
Global $desktopSize = WinGetPos("Program Manager")      ;Get the desktop size from Program Manager
Global $maxX = $desktopSize[2]; - 600                   ;Set a Max X Position by using the width of our image and width of desktop
Global $maxY = $desktopSize[3]; - 255                   ;Set a Max Y position by using the height of our image and the height of desktop
Global $splashX = Int(Random(1, $maxX-1))               ;Display our splash randomly in the acceptable space
Global $splashY = Int(Random(1, $maxY-1))               ;Display our splash randomly in the acceptable space
Global $splashXVel = Int(Random(10,20))                 ;Setup a random velocity for our image
Global $splashYVel = 0;Int(Random(-5,5))                ;Setup a random velocity for our image (No need for Y Velocity anymore)

;////////////////////////////
;// Create and Display GUI //
;////////////////////////////
$Form1 = GuiCreate("Locked",400,280,$splashX, $splashY, $WS_POPUP, $WS_EX_LAYERED)              ;Create a GUI Window (Layered For Transparency)
$gifTest = ObjCreate("Shell.Explorer.2")                                                        ;Create a Shell.Explorer Object to display a GIF
$gifTest_ctrol = GuiCtrlCreateObj($gifTest,-5,-5,410,290)                                       ;Push it slightly out of our GUI bounds to hide the border
;                                                                                               ;Create a variable to hold some simple HTML code that displays a GIF
$URL = "about:<html><body bgcolor='#dedede' scroll='no'><img src='C:\Users\DT\Pictures\nyan-cat.gif'></img></body></html>"
$gifTest.Navigate($URL)                                                                         ;Point our shell explorer to our HTML code
_WinAPI_SetLayeredWindowAttributes($Form1, 0xdedede, 255)                                       ;Set our transparency color to our html background to make everything transparent
GUISetState(@SW_SHOW)                                                                           ;And finally, display our GUI

;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
;// Function that is called whenever a key is pressed //
;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Func _KeyProc($nCode, $wParam, $lParam)                                                         ;Grab parameters from our DLL Hook
   If $nCode < 0 Then Return _WinAPI_CallNextHookEx($keyboardHook, $nCode, $wParam, $lParam)    ;If it's not actually a key being pressed call the next hook
   $lock = True                                                                                 ;Otherwise, it's time to lock the computer
   Return 1                                                                                     ;Don't call the next hook (supress key press)
EndFunc

;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
;// Function that is called whenever the mouse moves  //
;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Func _MouseProc($nCode, $wParam, $lParam)                           ;Grab parameters from our DLL Hook
   randomizeVelocity()                                              ;randomize our splash velocity
   randomizePosition()                                              ;and randomize its position
   Return 1                                                         ;then supress the mouse movement
EndFunc

;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
;// Simple randomize functions to reuse code and for ease of reading  //
;///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Func randomizeVelocity()
   $splashXVel = Int(Random(10,20))
   ;$splashYVel = Int(Random(-3,3))
EndFunc
Func randomizePosition()
   $splashX = Int(Random(1, $maxX-1))
   $splashY = Int(Random(1, $maxY-1))
EndFunc

;/////////////////////////////////////////////////
;// Our program loop (main function basically)  //
;/////////////////////////////////////////////////
hideTaskbar();
While 1                                                             ;loop indefinitely (until we exit :))
   $splashX = $splashX + $splashXVel                                ;Modify splash x position by velocity
   $splashY = $splashY + $splashYVel                                ;Modify splash y position by velocity
   WinMove($Form1,"" , $splashX, $splashY)                          ;and move the window

   ;If $splashX >= $maxX Or $splashX <= 0 Then $splashXVel *= -1        ;if our splash image hits an edge
   ;If $splashY >= $maxY Or $splashY <= 0 Then $splashYVel *= -1        ;reverse its velocity (can be buggy! ;))
   If $splashX >= $maxX Then
      $splashY = Int(Random(1,$maxY-400))
      $splashX = -400;
   EndIf      

   If $lock Then                                                    ;If we have a message to lock the computer
      DllCallbackFree($stub_KeyProc)                                ;release our hooks
      DllCallbackFree($stub_MouseProc)
      _WinAPI_UnhookWindowsHookEx($keyboardHook)
      _WinAPI_UnhookWindowsHookEx($mouseHook)
      showTaskbar();
      Run("rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation")                ;and lock the computer
      Exit                                                          ;then exit the program :)
   EndIf
   Sleep(40)
WEnd
;/////////////////////////////////////////////////

Func hideTaskbar()
   WinSetTrans("[Class:Shell_TrayWnd]", "", 0)
   ControlHide('','', WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Button]"))
EndFunc
Func showTaskbar()
   WinSetTrans("[Class:Shell_TrayWnd]", "", 255)
   ControlShow('','', WinGetHandle("[CLASS:Button]"))
EndFunc
```

[image]

**Edit:**

In regards to the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> key combination (or other windows key combinations), checkout this link for info on how to disable those:

http://tamas.io/c-disable-ctrl-alt-del-alt-tab-alt-f4-start-menu-and-so-on/

Comment: I don't have AutoIT to test, but what happens if this is running and the user presses Alt+F4 (which by default closes the foreground application)? Does the machine still lock? If not, this isn't a solution, because it's a security issue that locking the workstation is meant to prevent.

Comment: The AutoIt program runs in the background, so it's not a foreground application that can be closed with Alt+F4. In the answer I also said: don't forget that you also need to go to extra lengths to lock CTRL+ALT+DELETE if you want to do it right because that's the real issue. It's possible, if you had expert timing, to hit CTRL+ALT+DELETE and maybe somehow close the program through blind luck or something - which is why I mentioned it.

Comment: I edited my comment with info on how to disable built in windows key combinations :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution but it will not solve my issue.

In our project, we deploy EXE in customer's computer, where the EXE detects the extended displays and 
assign dashboards to the respective displays.

Once all Extended displays showing dashboards, the primary computer can go into lock mode or sleep mode.
but Extended displays should not be locked they should continuously show dashboards.

we are using Windows forms C# VS2013

Comment: I don't think you understand how sleep works. The computer saves its current state to ram and powers down almost everything else. Running processes are suspended and the hard drive is powered down ... programs cannot keep running while the machine is asleep. You would have to alter the operating system functionality or the functionality of the lock screen to do what you are trying to do.